# Young's double-slit in Sound waves

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics

I am going my physics extended essay and I am stuck in explaining my hypothesis. So I am doing an experiment where I have 2 sound sources emitting specific frequencies and I am trying to find fringe (first maximum or the point of constructive interference). Now the problem is I have to use theory to explain why the point of the first constructive interference will decrease as the frequency of emitted sound waves increases. Anyone have an idea please?

Comment: You have to ask yourself what interference is. Why does it occur and when?

Comment: have a look http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/slits.html

Comment: What do you mean by "decrease"?  Do you mean decrease in amplitude?  Will the slit spacing and slit width remain constant as you increase sound frequency?

Comment: Re, "2 sound sources emitting specific frequencies..." You're not going to find much of an interference pattern if the two sources are not emitting the _same_ specific frequency. Your two sources simulate the two slits which, in the classic double-slit experiment, both would be illuminated by the _same_ laser.

Comment: Also, the results may be hard to interpret if you don't perform the experiment in some approximation of an _[anechoic chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anechoic_chamber)_. (Maybe out of doors with the sound sources suspended above a grassy field). Otherwise, reflections off the walls, floors, ceilings, and other surfaces will create a complex pattern--as if many additional sound sources were present.

Comment: Both speakers are emitting the same frequency, so for example if both speakers are separated by 30cm, emitting 500Hz at the same time, and there is nothing in front of the speakers there will be an open area and only a 1 m long screen in front of the speakers that Is 50cm away from the speakers. Now I have to find the first fringe using this formula, s = λD/d, and I have to explain using theory how and why the first fringe (s) will get closer to the central maximum as the frequency increases. I will take measurement separately though, so I wont change the frequency as I am taking measurements